# Event capturing on D3 SVG element fireong only on "window"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, dom-events

### [Demo page](https://jsfiddle.net/54g15bqk/5/)

D3 Version `4.0` [prevents some events](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#api-reference) from bubbling up when calling `d3.zoom()`, so if I want to [capture a `mouseup` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for example on the SVG element itself, this creates a problem. 
Events listeners are "blocked", so for example the below code wouldn't work:

```
document.querySelector('svg').addEventListener("mouseup", function(e){
    alert(1)
}, true);
```

Even if the SVG is inside a another element, event capture won't work on that element. not even on "document.body".
it will **only** work when applied to the `window` object:

```
window.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e){
    alert( 'TYPE: '+e.type + '\nTARGET: '+e.target )
}, true);
```

Why does capturing only work on the `window` object?

Comment: I have the exact same question 3 years later, except for d3 brush. Did you happen to have any luck with this?

Comment: @mb7744 - Sorry but i don't remember. I think there was a thread at the time on D3 github, and Mike gave some workaround

Comment: I've been digging around in the debugger and it seems that at least in the case of d3 brush, event listeners that stop propagation are added to the window object once the brush is started. So this would explain the behaviour. Not sure if this is a bug or intended but either way it's very hard to work around.